# How to make VS2010 Gridview not display the millisecond of a column type of 'time'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a table called `testtable` that have a column named `expire_time` of type [time]

The problem is that when I perform a sql queries using a datasource in Visual Studio 2010 such as:

```
select * from testtable
```

The Gridview will give me something like the following:

```
===================================
|   ID   |  expire_time           |
===================================
|  1     | 17:18:19:0370000       |
|  2     | 20:11:19:0680000       |
===================================
```

Is it possible to let my Gridview display the following?

```
===========================
| ID   |  expire_time     |
===========================
|  1     | 17:18:19       |
|  2     | 20:11:19       |
===========================
```

Comment: you could always let the SQL-Statement do your work (aka SELECT ID, CONVERT([format], expire_time) FROM testtable -- guessing ms sqlserver involved)

Comment: @Najzero, I thought that there might be a property in Gridview that can allow me to hide the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot in your SQL Statement: select convert(varchar, getdate(), 1)